# Custom menu on search page missing

Tags: wordpress, search, header, menu

I've been scratching my head over this one, so thanks in advance for any help. Much appreciated.

I've got a menu in WP 3.0.1 which I call in header.php using:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
```

It's showing up fine on every page **apart** from search results. The search.php file starts with a standard `get_header();` so it must be the `wp_nav_menu` code right? But nothing's wrapped in an `is_search()` conditional or anything.

The output HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a>Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a>Link 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But instead, it gets as far as the `<ul>` and doesn't output any `<li>`s:

```
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Most strange. Has anyone else come across this before? Is it just far too late and I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ZoulRic's code works fine, but it breaks the search function in the Media Library. To prevent this add:

```
if( !is_admin() )
```

just before the last line, so your code look like:

```
function menu_fix_on_search_page( $query ) {
   if(is_search()){
       $query->set( 'post_type', array(
        'attachment', 'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'film', 'music'
          ));
         return $query;
         }
   }
if( !is_admin() ) add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'menu_fix_on_search_page' );
```

Comment: good spot on the media library search. pretty sure this has since been solved in core but I thought I should accept an answer anyways.

Comment: I did exact the same thing, but the nav disappears anyway.. I just customized my search query a bit: code: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/make-archives-php-include-custom-post-types/#comment-1594317  can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4):

You may may have set a filter that is intercepting the query responsible for generating the navigation menu links, or more specifically, overriding the 'nav_menu_item' post type required by the query object.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
function menu_fix_on_search_page( $query ) {
    if(is_search()){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array(
         'post', 'nav_menu_item'
            ));
          return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'menu_fix_on_search_page' );
```

Paste this into functions.php in your theme files.

Comment: I had the same problem only pages were listed on my search page, your code fixed that.

Comment: Glad it did helped you :)

Wordpress treats navigation as a post type, so all we need to do is to include it in the wordpress search page

Comment: I did exact the same thing, but the nav disappears anyway.. I just customized my search query a bit: code: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/make-archives-php-include-custom-post-types/#comment-1594317  can somebody help me?

Comment: Wow! Greatness! Thank you!!